# Blending sword motion with sword swing sound in VR

Tags: unity, audio, virtual-reality, sound-effects

At first, this may seem like an easy problem to solve. I also thought so. (This was a one tick task in my Trello board). But in VR the players' weapon (Sword) swings are unpredictable. The direction of the swing and speed can change very rapidly. It is hard to blend the swing sound (Whoosh) with the sword motion.

The easiest solution is to just play the sound when the weapon velocity magnitude is at a high level. I also added a small countdown of 0.1s wait before consecutive weapon swing sounds. This kind of works but not all the time. Because at the end of the swing, when I change the weapon direction I hear the "Whoosh" sound again, which is very odd.

Just want to know how to properly blend the weapon swing sound with sword motion.